# How to check if weight is between two values

Tags: vb.net

What's the best way to check if weight are between the range using the If condition?
Ex:

```
If textbox.text (between) value X - value Z then
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use standard equal operators like this:

```
If (Val(TextBox.Text) >= ValueX) And (Val(TextBox.Text) <= ValueZ) Then
' etc...
```

**Val** function extracts numbers from string.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend against blindly recommending use of Val.

Comment: Also, consider using `AndAlso` and recommend to extract the result of parsing the number into a variable instead of repeating it.