# Is there a more elegant way to check that a number is between 2 values?

Tags: vb.net

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71673922/how-to-check-if-weight-is-between-two-values

In here we pretty much use If, then, and well, And.

What?

VB.net has no built in function for "between" something.

Comment: The closest you can get in VB.NET is @Julian answer.
C# 9 (also .NET) introduces some new functioanllity which allows for what you are after with Pattern Matching Enhancements but unfortunatly there is no equivalent in VB.NET https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#pattern-matching-enhancements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, there is no built in functionality. You can though create an extension method which extends the Integer.

```
Public Module Extensions

    <Extension>
    Public Function IsBetween(number As Integer, numberFrom As Integer, numberTo As Integer) As Boolean
        Return number >= numberFrom AndAlso number <= numberTo
    End Function

End Module
```

An example call is then:

```
    Dim number As Integer = 10, numberFrom As Integer = 4, numberTo As Integer = 14

    Dim isBetween As Boolean = number.IsBetween(numberFrom, numberTo)
```